# How to align text to specific position in PDFCell in IText

Tags: itext, text-alignment

I need your help in positioning some text to specific location in the line rather than using left, center or right alignment in `PDFCell`. I have some text that needs to be aligned after the center of the `PDFCell`. Currently, the code is aligning the text to the center, however I need to give it more spaces to the right:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("\u0625\u0644\u0649 \u0645\u0646 \u064a\u0647\u0645\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0645\u0631",font));
table.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.addCell(cell);
doc.add(table);
```

So how can I achieve this.

Comment: How about adding spaces manually? That works for me

Comment: @mustangDC spaces will work but this will create alignment problems along with the other below lines. I am looking for something that is similar to align the x-axis or something like that if it is there

Comment: Your concept is correct about `x-axis`, but what I am taking about is a li'l hack. I have noticed that `exceeding spaces will not be counted if it is greater than the size of the column`. Ultimately it won't dismantle the below lines. You can check once. I may be wrong as it can be `iText` version dependent also but it's worth a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it by creating a function that creates spaces and append it to the paragraph:

```
  String addspace(int i, String str) {
        StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            str1.append(" ");
        }
        str1.append(str);
        return str1.toString();

    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to complicate things? I already told you that `PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("                     WhatEver you want here              ",font));` will work right?

Comment: with spaces, you did the same thing, you could have done that without increasing the complexity and adding in more code. `Simple blank spaces inside the paragraph would have worked`